# Calling C# component from JavaScript in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, winjs

I'm trying to use Windows Runtime Component (C#) in my Windows 10 Universal App (JavaScript).
I found how to do that in Windows 8.x store apps:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779077.aspx
but this solution is not working with Windows 10 Universal App. It is throwing exception that class is not registered in the JavaScript.

WRC code:

```
namespace SampleComponent
{
    public sealed class Example
    {
        public static string GetAnswer() 
        { 
            return "The answer is 42."; 
        }

        public int SampleProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In JS:

```
 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML =
        SampleComponent.Example.getAnswer();
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code that makes the call from JavaScript to the WRC?

Comment: @Sorskoot I tried to use code from MSDN example for Widnows 8.x WRC (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779077.aspx#DiveRightIn). Code added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The any CPU mode is not available (by default) if you develop a Windows 10 app written with XAML/C# or an app written with HTML/JS using a WinRT component written with C# because of the ".Net native"

You have to target the good platform :)

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found that this problem occurs when building in Any CPU mode. For x86/x64 it is working properly. This solution is enough for me at this moment. I will post more information here if I found how to run it on other platforms.